# href on a div with the exception of one element

Tags: php, html, css

I made a "musicbox" which shows a music cover and when hovered over it shows a toggleable playbutton, to either play or pause the music.
Now what i want to achieve is the following:

- When clicked ON the play/pause button the music will play or pause (did this part)
- when clicking anywhere on the cover except the play/pause button it should link (href?) to another page

I tried several things but cannot get the playbutton excluded from the href, i think it should remain inside the ".overlay" because they contents need to be hidden unless you hover over the div/musicbox

```
echo"
                <div class='musicbox' align='center'>
                    <a>
                        <div class='overlay'>
                            <img data-value='../../admin/uploads/tracks/".$music_track."' 
                            data-value='../../admin/uploads/tracks/".$music_oggfile."' 
                            onclick='updateSource(this)' class='btnplay' src='../media/images/go.png'></img>
                            <img class='btnpause' src='../media/images/stop.png'></img>
                            <div class='desc'>".$music_title."</div>
                        </div>
                    </a>
                    <img class='cover' src='../../admin/uploads/images/".$music_image."' width='350' height='350'>
                </div>";
```

Comment: here are some images to give an idea of the layout: normal, http://imgur.com/KtYhfu3 and hover http://imgur.com/muH6qaG